# How to insert future date/time from Excel into Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm automating a letter that has to go out individually to 300+ people. The names are different for each letter but dates and times are also different. I am using Excel for the data and using VBA in Powerpoint to fill the text boxes with the correct information. 
The date keeps formatting to 6/27/2019. I need it to say "June 27, 2019".
The time keeps formatting to "0.583333333333333" when it is suppose to say "2:00 PM".  These are the only issues I keep having.

I've tried changing the line of code to this:
`oSld.Shapes("ClassDate").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("E2").NumberFormat = "mmm dd, yyyy"`

This provides a 'False' in the Text Form on Powerpoint. I have not figured out how to fix the time code.

`````
oSld.Shapes("MName").TextFrame.TextRange.Text=oWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value
oSld.Shapes(“MName1”).TextFrame.TextRange.Text=oWB.Sheets(1).Range(“A2”).Value
oSld.Shapes("HAName").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value
oSld.Shapes("HAName1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value
oSld.Shapes("WMWeek").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value
oSld.Shapes("ClassDate").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("E2").Value
oSld.Shapes("ClassTime").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oWB.Sheets(1).Range("F2").Value````


I expect the ClassDate output to be what is in range E2, June 27, 2019.
I expect the ClassTime output to be what is in range F2, 2:00 PM.
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Format function. Two examples:

```
...=Format(oWB.Sheets(1).Range("E2").Value,"MMM dd, yyyy")
...=Format(oWB.Sheets(1).Range("F2").Value,"hh:mm")
```

Read more about the formatting codes in the documentation